# Error Connecting to GitoLite from Staging Server - ECONNREFUSED Deploy Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, capistrano, rvm-capistrano

I'm having a little trouble trying to deploy a previously working project to the development server. I did not set-up the system however I do have all the credentials I need (I think).

After trying cap staging deploy I get so far and then it produces an error. Please see below:

```
triggering load callbacks
  * 2012-11-20 14:52:20 executing `staging'
    triggering start callbacks for `deploy'
  * 2012-11-20 14:52:20 executing `multistage:ensure'
Identity added: /Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/XXX/.ssh/id_rsa)
  * 2012-11-20 14:52:20 executing `deploy'
  * 2012-11-20 14:52:20 executing `deploy:update'
 ** transaction: start
  * 2012-11-20 14:52:20 executing `deploy:update_code'
    executing locally: "git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@repo1:2011/proto_projectname_rails HEAD"
    command finished in 2864ms
  * executing "git clone -q ssh://gitolite@repo1:2011/proto_projectname_rails /var/www/projectname/releases/20121120145223 && cd /var/www/projectname/releases/20121120145223 && git checkout -q -b deploy 0598169ed07015279bd78efa91f25ed3e5edcad8 && (echo 0598169ed07015279bd78efa91f25ed3e5edcad8 > /var/www/projectname/releases/20121120145223/REVISION)"
    servers: ["repo2"]
*** [deploy:update_code] rolling back
  * executing "rm -rf /var/www/projectname/releases/20121120145223; true"
    servers: ["repo2"]
 ** [deploy:update_code] exception while rolling back: Capistrano::ConnectionError, connection failed for: repo2 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2))
connection failed for: repo2 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2))
```

deploy.rb

```
set :stages, %w(staging production)
set :default_stage, "production"
require 'capistrano/ext/multistage'

set :application, "projectname"

set :scm, :git
set :repository,  "ssh://gitolite@repo1:2011/proto_projectname_rails"
```

I am honestly confused as to why a previously working version no longer functions.

Any help, advice or guidance or this matter is more than welcome.

Thank you

As a side note, yes it has always been the non-standard port of 2011 and is in my .ssh/config

Edit:

There are 2 servers involved in this process.

After running the following locally and on 2nd server I do get a response.

```
git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@repo1:2011/proto_projectname_rails
```

It returns;

```
0598169ed07015279bd78efa91f25ed3e5edcad8    HEAD
0598169ed07015279bd78efa91f25ed3e5edcad8    refs/heads/master
```

Edit: Runs on 2 servers. Repo1 and Repo2

```
cap deploy:check
```

Returns

```
   triggering load callbacks
 * 2012-11-27 21:02:36 executing `production'
 triggering start callbacks for `deploy:check'
 * 2012-11-27 21:02:36 executing `multistage:ensure'
  Identity added: /Users/x/.ssh/id_rsa (/Users/x/.ssh/id_rsa)
 * 2012-11-27 21:02:36 executing `deploy:check'
 * executing "test -d /var/www/projectname/releases"
   servers: ["repo2"]
   connection failed for: repo2 (Errno::ECONNREFUSED: Connection refused - connect(2))
```

**Solved**

It turns out that it was being rejected due to the 2nd servers port number. Adding

```
set :port, 1893
```

The bounty is still open to anyone that can explain this.

Why could always SSH into the server, without editing my ssh/config at anytime, and were other machines able to deploy, with the exact same deploy and staging files, but I could not until I explicitly added the port number?

Comment: The error is when you connect to gitolite from the staging server (`git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@XXX:2011`).  Please edit your question and post the top part of your `deploy.rb`

Comment: HI. Thanks for the guidance. Edited the post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**See update 2 below for the final answer to this question**

OK, so first thing to test is whether, from your local computer, you can run `git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@XXX:2011` -- it should return the list of references from the repo.  If this doesn't work, it should probably give you a similar error (connection refused or similar), and then you probably need to figure out why from whoever is hosting the git repo.

If it does work locally, then you might need to set some or all of these options, depending on how you want to access git while you're deploying.  I think the forward_agent option is needed unless your deploy server/user can log into the repository directly.

```
set :deploy_via, :remote_cache
default_run_options[:pty] = true
ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true
```

and I described how to set that up in [this other stack overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476138/setting-up-private-github-access-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk-and-ruby-container/13476637#13476637).

The key thing to remember about capistrano is that most commands are really just standard shell commands, but are passed to the remote server using ssh, as in `ssh user@server.example.com <command>`, so that would be another thing to test if you can't get this working.

Update based on information added to original question:

When you make a TCP connection to a server using a URL, you specify protocol, host address, and port number.  Port number is implied for many protocols.  E.g. `ssh://1.2.3.4` specifies the protocol SSH whose standard port is 22, thus would be the same as `ssh://1.2.3.4:22`.  I am guessing your git provider assigns different ports to different repositories (perhaps on the same IP address) in order to route requests, so for each of your repos you may have a different port number.  Because it is not the default port for the ssh protocol being used, it must be specified as part of the URL (and it seems you can override this in capistrano using `set :port`).

It does not make sense to me that you would have multiple git repositories (`repo1` and `repo2`) for the same project so perhaps I need to understand in what cases this happens, but in any case, the reason for the error was that your server could not make an TCP connection to the git host given the supplied URL.

**Update 2**
OK, so it turns out that `repo1` is a git repository.  It is hosted at a non-standard SSH port (`2011`) so this needs to embedded in the URL whenever referring to the ssh URL of the git server.

However, `repo2` is actually just the application server that runs the Rails app (hosted by the same source as the git repo), and it is *also* available on a non-standard ssh port (`1893`).  In order to ssh into this server, you will need to specify the port using `ssh -p 1893 ...` -- and since this is how capistrano connects, so will it.  This is why adding the `set :port, 1893` is required.

Comment: After running git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@x.x.x.x:2011/proto_projectname_rails It returns
0598169ed07015279bd78efa91f25ed3e5edcad8 HEAD
0598169ed07015279bd78efa91f25ed3e5edcad8 refs/heads/master. This is a positive thing right? Is there any way I would easily know what options I should set as default? (the sysadmin jumped ship with no support)

Comment: Did you check the link I posted (just below the section on the variables you need to set)?

Comment: Ahh I missed that. On it. Cheers for your help 'til now

Comment: The project isn't hosted on GitHub but on a private server. Will this change the options that need to be set? I tried adding those 3 to my deploy file and it still failed

Comment: No, your git repo doesn't matter (mostly).  I was probably mistaken when I said that the problem was when capistrano ran the `git ls-remote` command, I hadn't noticed the next command starts with `git clone...` and significantly, while the first is run locally by capistrano, the second is run on the remote server.  Getting set up with `ssh-agent`, and then using `ssh-add`, both locally, should allow ssh to pass along your credentials (which we know work on your git repo) so they can be used by the server.  I think the `ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true` is the setting needed in cap.

Comment: So if I purely add `ssh_options[:forward_agent]` = true should it fix the issue? As I have added this to my deploy file and I am still getting the same error...

Comment: Well, you may be in for a little manual reading, and/or experimentation.  It is my understanding that if you 1) have `ssh-agent` running, and 2) have used `ssh-add <your-private-key>`, and 3) used this `ssh_options[:forward_agent] = true` then the ssh credentials used on the remote host are passed from your local machine.  You'll know when the issue is fixed when it works.  I am just trying to help you understand.  I cannot fix the problem for you.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for your help thus far. I will hit the manuals and update if I get lucky

Comment: I noticed that there are 2 servers involved. one which has the user gitolite and another. When I ssh onto the other server I cannot run the `code`git ls-remote`code` command as it asks for a pass (which I don't know). Should the two servers be able to talk to each other? Does it seem like the SSH key has been removed as it used to work? Thanks

Comment: If the "other" server is the one you're deploying to, then yes, it needs to be able to access the git server using credentials (usually an SSH public key) of a trusted user.  We have verified that you have those credentials (running the `git ls-remote` command from your computer).  The other computer probably does not.  Two ways to solve the problem: 1) give the user account on the "other" computer access to the git server, i.e. create/install that user's public key on the git server, or 2) "forward" your credentials via ssh-agent and ssh-add so that your account can access git from "other".

Comment: I am able to run git ls-remote from the 1st box to the 2nd. I must admit I am pretty confused as to why I can run the command but it is still failing. Do you know of any way to view more verbose logs? Or perhaps logs to check on the server(s)? Thanks

Comment: If 1st box means "other" and 2nd means "gitolite", and on 1st/other you are logged in as the same user as you use to do your cap deploys, this means 1st/other has proper git credentials.  You should be able to also do `git pull`, `git clone` and so on.  If so, then you can use either the first OR second ways to solve the problem I mentioned earlier today.

Comment: Hi I managed to solve it by stating the non-standard port number in the deploy file. I've offered a bounty to an explanation as to why other users didn't need to include this line to their deploy file. Could their ssh/config be set differently? Thanks for your help

Comment: How did you do that?  The port was always present in the URL for the repository value.  The port would *absolutely, unequivocally* be required in all cases (unless it also formerly responded on the standard port 22 for ssh, as well and now doesn't).  Have you talked with whoever hosts your git repository?

Comment: Unfortunately the old sysadmin voluntarily took a redundancy package and is is now refusing to help...my local ssh/config has always had port 1893 for repo2 stated and I am unsure if it responded on both ports before. The entire project is in a complete mess and is so full of custom hacks and code that I don't think I will ever understand what it does. Thanks for your patience with this one, I'm not sure if any others can really learn from this one...

Comment: oh it may be something to point out. repo1 uses 2011 and repo2 uses 1893. so 2 servers and 2 different ports.

Comment: Yes, that may indeed be something to point out :-).  I have updated my original answer with an explanation.

Comment: Ok so just for clarification repo1 is the server stated in the deploy file first, so all the shell commands, including the ssh, are executed from repo1 and using that user, in this case gitolite? and so to ssh to repo2 on port 1893 gitolite's ssh/config would need to explicitly say this or the ssh command would need to read along the lines of ssh -p 1893 diffuser@repo2?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I am terribly confused as to why you would have two repositories in the same project.  I once saw someone setting up a separate repository for development vs production, but this is, for lack of a better word "wrong" :-).  Why do you have 2 repositories for a single Rails project?

Comment: You are not the only one who is confused. The project does have dev and prod. repo1 looks to contain the git repo1(server1) with repo2(server2) serving the application(s). In all honesty it looks as though the sysadmin purposefully changed some configs on exit to try and ensure some further work on a contractual basis. All of this is rather a lot for me seeing as I am only a dev (front-end at that)...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20399/discussion-between-tom-harrison-jr-and-edwardgd)