# Setting up SSH keys for github private repo access on Elastic Beanstalk

Tags: node.js, git, ssh, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, ebextensions

My Node.JS project contains references to private NPM repos hosted on github. This works fine locally, but I'm struggling to get this working on Elastic Beanstalk.

```
dependencies: {
  ...
  "express": "^4.12.4",
  "jsonwebtoken": "^5.0.5",
  "my-private-module": "git@github.com:<my-user>/<my-repo>.git#<my-version>",
  ...
}
```

-

**What I need is to be able to set up a working SSH configuration for git on my Elastic Beanstalk instances, without having to store secret keys etc in source control.**

Obviously, the EB instances do not have the needed SSH keys to access my private github repos. If I use HTTPS style git URL's with `username:password@github.com` inlined, it works fine. It also works using the [oauth token method](https://help.github.com/articles/creating-a-personal-access-token-for-the-command-line/) offered by github (which is essentially a user:pass). But I do not want any credentials to be checked in to source control, so I'm trying to get cloning from github to work via SSH on my EB instances.

I've tried a million ways, including `npm preinstall` scripts according to [this blog post](http://fiznool.com/blog/2015/05/20/an-alternative-to-npm-private-modules/), which used to work until npm2 where a change made preinstall to run after the tree is built, and the PR to fix that issue is still pending.

I've tried an `.ebextensions` commands configuration that tries to call `git config` to place an `insteadof` on git@github.com into a HTTPS URL with an OAUTH token coming from an environment variable (tricky in itself since env variables aren't set at this time in the startup cycle, and the lack of $HOME makes git config confused).

I've also tried various different ways using `.ebextensions` to setup SSH on my EB instances, including [this solution from the comments on the mentioned blog post](https://gist.github.com/rohang07/fdf1d1caf0048968424d#file-01_setupssh-config). This is basically where I'm stuck now.

- I have successfully created a key pair, set it up on my github profile, and verified that the private key is usable from my local client to clone my repo
- I have put my private key and a ssh config file on a private S3 bucket
- I've created an `.ebextensions` `files` configuration which copies these two files from my S3 bucket into `/tmp/.ssh/`, according to [this example](https://gist.github.com/rohang07/fdf1d1caf0048968424d#file-01_setupssh-config)
- I've created a debug `commands` `.ebextensions` configuration which lists /tmp/.ssh and shows that the files were downloaded from S3 successfully:

/tmp/.ssh/config contains:

```
Host github.com
    IdentityFile /tmp/.ssh/deploy_key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

/tmp/.ssh/deploy_key contains my private key which is verified to work locally.

However, git still throws an error:

```
npm ERR! Command failed: git clone --template=/tmp/.npm/_git-remotes/_templates --mirror ssh://git@github.com/[.....]
npm ERR! Cloning into bare repository '/tmp/.npm/_git-remotes/git-ssh-git-github-com-[...]
npm ERR! Host key verification failed.
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

I am now running out of ideas. My best guess would be that /tmp/.ssh is not the path where git goes to look for the ssh config file - it might have been when the linked solution was proposed but might have changed in later AMI:s etc. The environment used when EB is starting up seems to be a bit limited; commands are run as user `nodejs` but /tmp seems to be used as the home directory, even though $HOME is not set anywhere.

How can I get git to pick up my SSH config, and consequently use my SSH key? How can I find out where git looks for a SSH config file? Normally it's in ~/.ssh, but since $HOME is not set, well... This should be easy but is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After a full day's struggle and finally stumbling over [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31946019/1226020) to a very similar question I had previously missed, it turns out the correct place to put ssh keys in order to be picked up by git on EB is in `/root/.ssh`, *not* `/tmp/.ssh`, *not* `/home/ec2-user/.ssh`.

My final configuration (assuming there's a private SSH key located in a S3 bucket at `<my-bucket>/github-eb-key`, and the corresponding public key is registered with a github user having access to the repo(s)), using an AMI configured as `64bit Amazon Linux 2016.09 v3.3.0 running Node.js`, and with the following in `.ebextensions/01_ssh_setup.config`:

```
Resources: 
  AWSEBAutoScalingGroup: 
    Metadata: 
      ? "AWS::CloudFormation::Authentication"
      : 
        S3Auth: 
          buckets: 
            - <my-bucket>
          roleName: 
            ? "Fn::GetOptionSetting"
            : 
              DefaultValue: aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role
              Namespace: "aws:asg:launchconfiguration"
              OptionName: IamInstanceProfile
          type: s3
files: 
  /root/.ssh/github-eb-key: 
    authentication: S3Auth
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    source: "https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/<my-bucket>/github-eb-key"
  /root/.ssh/config: 
    mode: "000600"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      Host github.com
        IdentityFile /root/.ssh/github-eb-key
        IdentitiesOnly yes
        UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
        StrictHostKeyChecking no
```

Comment: I've noticed this does not work if using package-lock.json and I haven't been able to figure out why. It appears NPM is doing something different with the install if pulling the data from package-lock.json. I added package-lock.json to the .egignore file and that works but could lead to version mismatches on deploy.