# Gitolite Authentication Issue from Remote Server

Tags: git, deployment, gitolite

I am having trouble running a simple command (which is part of a larger deploy process problem) on one sever from another.

user gitolite:

I can ssh using that user onto the box as it returns

```
X@repo2:~$ ssh gitolite@repo1
PTY allocation request failed on channel 0
hello repo2, this is gitolite v2.1-19-g36dfb85 running on git 1.7.0.4
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
     R   W      proto_projectname_rails
    @R_ @W_     testing
Connection to repo1.x closed.
```

However when I try run git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@repo1.x:2011/proto_projectname_rails it prompts for a password.

my gitolite.conf has the lines

```
repo    proto_projectname_rails
    RW+     =   MBP
    RW+     =   repo2
```

and the public key is in my keydir with the same name e.g. repo2.pub. 
I also ran

```
gl-setup repo2.pub
```

which updated the authorised_keys to include repo2 in there.

I am all out of ideas as to what else I need to do. If i run the same command from my local machine. i.e from MBP it completes successfully.

Any ideas on this would be more than welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: So `ssh gitolite@repo1.x:2011` works right? I mean, this is the `ssh` command you used to get the `gitolite` greeting message? And that message does mention you have `RW+` rights on `proto_projectname_rails` repo?

Comment: Yeah it returns a greeting message. i will update the message above with al it says and it does seem to have the R W

Comment: Ok, but `gitolite@repo1` is not the same than `gitolite@repo1.x:2011`, so would a `git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@repo1/proto_projectname_rails` would work? or `git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@repo1:proto_projectname_rails`?

Comment: running git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@repo1/proto_projectname_rails worked. Now I am confused. Do you mind looking at my other larger problem Q and seeing what I am doing wrong? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13476064/error-connecting-to-gitolite-from-staging-server-econnrefused-deploy-error)[link] If not thank you for your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ssh gitolite@repo1` works, then that is the ssh address you must use for gitolite.
Gitolite itself will call git, and the ssh settings on the server might use internally `gitolite@repo1.x:2011` for that git call.

But for the end-user, client of gitolite, `git ls-remote ssh://gitolite@repo1/proto_projectname_rails` will work.